# How to increase message size in grpc using python

Tags: python, server, client, message, grpc

I am using grpc for message passing and am testing a simple server and client.  When my message size goes over the limit, I get this error.

```
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with 
(StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT,
 Received message larger than max (7309898 vs. 4194304))>
```

How do I increase the message size on the server and client side?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Changing the `message_length` for both send and receive will do the trick.

```
channel = grpc.insecure_channel(
    'localhost:50051',
    options=[
        ('grpc.max_send_message_length', MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH),
        ('grpc.max_receive_message_length', MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH),
    ],
)
```

Comment: @duck maybe you only change the server or client? try change from both sides

Comment: is `MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH` a python or grpc default value or customer defined value?

Answer (score 16):

I had this problem, I solved it by setting the 'grpc.max_send_message_length' and 'grpc.max_receive_message_length' on both the client and the server:

In client (Credit to @Dumbo for this code snippet):

```
channel = grpc.insecure_channel(
    'localhost:50051',
    options=[
        ('grpc.max_send_message_length', MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH),
        ('grpc.max_receive_message_length', MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH),
    ],
)
```

In server:

```
server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10), options = [
        ('grpc.max_send_message_length', MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH),
        ('grpc.max_receive_message_length', MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH)
    ])
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the existing answers, you can find a list of all key-value pair options in the github repo - see below

**From the [grpc-Glossary](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/glossary.html#term-channel_arguments)**

> **channel_arguments**
> A list of key-value pairs to configure the underlying gRPC Core channel or server object. Channel arguments are meant for advanced usages and contain experimental API (some may not labeled as experimental). Full list of available channel arguments and documentation can be found under the “grpc_arg_keys” section of “grpc_types.h” header file (https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.43.x/include/grpc/impl/codegen/grpc_types.h). For example, if you want to disable TCP port reuse, you may construct channel arguments like: options = (('grpc.so_reuseport', 0),).

[image]

Answer (score -7):

You should not increase the message size.
 It comes with a performance penalty. 
 In real situations one implements paging to split too large messages.

Comment: maybe, but I still want to see if it is possible and what the performance penalty will be .

Comment: There is no golden setting that fits all environments